# sed pattern matching deletes content of file if it encounters space

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am using sed to replace first occurrence of `@@ID@@` from my configuration file with a text that user enters. The command used is:

```
sed '0,/\@\@ID\@\@/{s/\@\@ID\@\@/'$INPUT'/}' $config_file > $temp_file
mv $temp_file $config_file
```

Where INPUT is the value entered by user.
The above statement works fine if there is no space in the `INPUT` It goes and replace `@@ID@@` to value in `INPUT`. But when user enters text separated by space, all the contents in the config file are deleted. This is SCARY!

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Why do you escape the `@`? Also the explicit address it not necessary.  And quote your shell variables: `$INPUT` should be `"$INPUT"`

Comment: The escape for @ is not necessary - agreed, removed it. 
Surrounding the INPUT with "" solved it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this line a try:

```
 sed "0,/@@ID@@/{s/@@ID@@/$INPUT/}" file
```

Comment: Though I am curious. My above command doesn't work - I get it - but why would it delete all the contents of the file?

Comment: @am28 shell variable will get expanded in double quotes, not single ones.

Comment: but it works fine if the INPUT value doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: @Kent Why do you use the range?

Comment: IMHO `sed '0,/@@ID@/s//'"$INPUT"'/' file` is a safer bet as it isolates the sed commands from the shell. Of course the content of the variable may always cause unexpected results as all to frequently we see questions where unquoted delimiters are passed in. Also the metacharacter `&` unless quoted may be expanded to the lefthandside match. Less likely are backreferences being expanded by mistake or failing i.e. the variable contains `\n` where `n` is a single digit and the LHS of the sed command contains groupings (`(...)`).

Comment: @hek2mgl I used range `0,/../` because OP wants to replace the 1st occurrence in file not 1st in each line.